# Is it possible to insert a component or markdown to mail blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-blade

something like:

```
(new SomeMailable)->with([
    ‘content’ => ‘# Title’
]);
```

or

```
(new SomeMailable)->with([
    ‘content’ => ‘<x-mail::button url=“/”>Press</x-mail::button>’
]);
```

In the corresponding blade there is a `{!! $content !!}` taking this parameter. html tag works in this way, just wondering if passing more complicated stuff is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your markdown in a variable, pass it to view and render it with Markdown::parse  :

```
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($content) }}
```